# Add/Edit Shipment Address in Cart page can't be clicked

Tags: joomla2.5, shopping-cart, virtuemart

I have list of products, I fill in it's name, category, weight & dimension and other infos. Then I made a shipment method.  But when I go to the frontend and I try to purchase a product, the "Add/Edit Shipment Address" is not clickable even after I have already added the Billing Address Information. What is wrong with this? By the way, my shipment method is based on "weight,zip and country" and I set the product to have 0 weight , no zip and available to all countries.

I am using Virtuemart 2.0.26 and Joomla 2.5.16

Answer (score 0):

First of all the products have weight 0 is wrong

set to a valid weight. Next is you are making the products available to all countries so leave the zip code empty its wrong, You have to set the ship from zip code that is store zip code on vendor section.Also if you are using default weight,zip and country shipment plugin comes with VM(default) should use zip code range like `0 - 99999` to all zip codes.

For different countries you can't get exact shipment charge without using USPS or UPS shipment plugin.

Hope its clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sir. The website is actually selling gift certificates which doesn't need shipment, I was just planning to use the shipment information as the recipient information of the gift certificate. Anyway I just used another way in order to get the recipient details, and that is to add fields in the "Bill-to" information. Thanks again for your reply Sir.